# App not running on device with appStore Provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios7, provisioning-profile

I created a app and is available on App Store. 
Now I want to upload a new version of my app. I have a device that is register for my app. The app runs pretty good with the developer and distribution profiles.

But when I use the app-store provisioning profile and trying to installed the build on my device it's not installing.

So I just wanted to know that can we test our app on device with app store provisioning profiles? If yes, please tell me how can I achieve this. If not, then how can I able to know whether my build is perfect with app store provisioning profiles.

Comment: delete local app and then install from app store. as both app id are same, app store is not allowing you to install...

Comment: Thanks Fahim for your reply. But my new version of app is not available on apple store yet. I want to test my new version on device with the help of xcode (Same as  we test our app by attching device to xcode).So my question is it possible to test app on device with appstore provisioning profiles.

Comment: then answer is NO. with appstore provision profiles you cannot test app locally... if u test app with normal provision profile and it works correctly then it will also work with appstore provision  profile.. don't worry about htat...

Comment: Thanks Fahim.... I just  wanted to know that... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make your app (with app-store provisioning profile) available for beta testing from iTunesConnect itself.

Login to iTunesConnect and go to `Apps -> <You App> -> Test Flight`. Internal testers can test build available in beta without App Store approval.

Answer (score 0):

**Development profile:** - Used in development phase of the app to run the app on simulator and developer devices. (If a developer device is not in this list the in-development app can not be installed).

**Ad-Hoc Distribution:** Distribution builds of an app, which can be installed on 100 devices designated by the developer on his provisioning portal. The distribution mechanism can be websites, mails or OTA. These type of builds are generally for beta testing or demos.

**App-store Distribution:** Distribution builds that are intended for general public(for sale). The distribution mechanism is App store only. **You cannot install this build from Xcode directly or by dragging .ipa file using iTunes**